# Android One to many

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am trying to learn my ways around using Android way of doing things. So as a project I am building an app. I managed to do initial bits of layouts, forms fine. I am struck at the following.

**Brief Overview**
I have an Author class and Book class. A book can have multiple authors and like wise an author can write multiple books.

I have working layouts and activities for Authors and Books. Data is getting saved in sqlite db. (All good here)

I also have a layout screen for adding multiple authors for a book. There is a join table that holds multiple authors ids for a book. This table (BookAuthor) has following columns(_id, bookid, authorid). Example data is(1, 2223, 43)

**Problem**
When user enters the BookAuthor activity, they search and add multiple authors to the book. This is also working. My trouble is

1. how to display the list of authors with names that are already assigned to the book in the list view with a delete button
2. How to delete that entry from the join table when user clicks delete button for that listview row in the list

Can someone please point me in the right direction with good ref points or even short examples

Thanks
R

Comment: So you would like to know how to add and remove some items from a ListView, is that correct?

Comment: So you would like to read the names from the sqlite database and put them in a ListView, and then add a "delete" button to the activity that removes a row from the database, does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, but when deleted the record in the joining table is removed instead of the actual author. ie. just the relationship is removed between the author and book.

Comment: You should start by posting some code and layout xml files. Your post seems like a homework assignment and wanting to get help. But you get more help, much more, if you show your efforts and research.

Comment: Sorry, its not an assignment :-)...i was not expecting anyone to give me code. Like I mentioned above, all i was expecting is some suggestions or pointers to some good references. I haven't written code to accomplish this yet so cant post any code :-(